# printing character with double variable in c

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    char sign1='-',sign2='-' ;

    double x=-1,y=4,radius=9;

        if(x<0.0)
        {
            sign1='+';
            x=x*-1;
        }
        if(y<0.0) {
            sign2='+';
            y=y*-1;
        }

        printf("(x %c %.3lf)^2 + (y %c %.3lf)^2=%.3lf^2\n",x,sign1,y,sign2,radius);//here doesn't print the values of sign1 and sign2

        printf("%c %c\n",sign1,sign2);//here prints properly;

    return 0;
}
```

In my code, the first `printf` function doesn't work properly. It should print `(x + 1.000)^2 + (y - 4.000)^2 = 9.000^2` but the output I get is

```
(x   0.000)^2 + (y   0.000)^2 = 9.000^2
```

Why?

Comment: The order of your arguments to `printf` does not match its _format specification_

Comment: Try `sign1, x, sign2, y, radius` for parameters perhaps ?

Comment: "printf function doesn't work properly" - rather, "I fail to use the printf function properly"...

Answer (score 2):

### `printf` is not type safe!

Any mismatch in the actual type passed to `printf` and the format specifier specified for it results in **Undefined Behavior**.

`sign1` and `sign2` are declared as `char` so using `%f` results in Undefined Behavior.

---

You messed up the ordering of parameters to `printf`,

```
printf("(x %c %.3lf)^2 + (y %c %.3lf)^2=%.3lf^2\n",x,sign1,y,sign2,radius);
```

should be:

```
printf("(x %c %.3lf)^2 + (y %c %.3lf)^2=%.3lf^2\n",sign1,x,sign2,y,radius);
```

Comment: The funny thing is that with my gcc, the UB results in the intended output being produced, since the floating point arguments are passed in floating point registers :-o

Answer (score 1):

Correct this line as

```
printf("(x %c %.3lf)^2 + (y %c %.3lf)^2=%.3lf^2\n",sign1,x,sign2,y,radius);
```